# Android how to use checkedtextview

Tags: android, checkedtextview

the title speaks for itself. I am over several articles, topics and still haven't figured out how to use checkedtextview. I want a listview with checkable items.
In the following code i am using a listview and populating it with a string array. But how to change it to checkedtextview?

delete.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:id="@+id/linlay0"
     android:background="@color/list_bg">
  <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView00"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D8D8D8"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:height="40px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
     <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

delete_lv.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/list_content"
android:textColor="#222222"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="sample"
android:layout_margin="4dip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Delete.java:

```
public class Delete extends Activity {

    ListView lv1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    private String lv_items[] = { "Android", "iPhone", "BlackBerry",
                 "AndroidPeople", "J2ME", "Listview", "ArrayAdapter", "ListItem",
                 "Us", "UK", "India" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.delete);

TextView tv0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView00);
tv0.setText("Deletes");

lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Delete.this,R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content, lv_items);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

Answer (score 17):

In your xml file you're using textview as list item. Instead of that use `CheckedTextView`. You can directly drag and drop that from your widgets palette. You can use the `CheckedTextView` as both `TextView` and `CheckBox`. Below is an example if how to use it

```
   <CheckedTextView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
      style="@style/NormalText"  
      android:id="@+id/checkList" 
      android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
      android:paddingRight="20dip" 
      android:paddingTop="10dip"
      android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"  
      android:gravity="center_vertical"  
      android:checkMark="@drawable/our_checkbox"></CheckedTextView>
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get the checkbox on the left side of the text ?

Comment: Note: `our_checkbox` must be a `selector` with defined `android:state_checked="true"` state

Comment: If all you need is the default Android checkbox look use android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"

Comment: There is  a property called fontFamily, can I use custom fonts in it? Cant find it on official [API Doc page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html).

Comment: _If_ you are using multiselect then you might want to use instead `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `android:drawableLeft` to set the checkbox on left. You can use the code snippet below for achieving it.

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_radio_check"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#3d484d"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    />
```

This will move your selector to left side of text. You can adjust the rest of the parameters like padding, gravity, etc.

Comment: But but.. this is exacly what CheckBox does.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code to use the default CheckdTextView in android

```
<CheckedTextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingRight="6dip"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="- Action finished"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my use in SingleChoiceDialog

1.select_dialog_singlechoice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/PopupSelectList"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/radio"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="12.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip" />
```

2.style.xml

```
<style name="PopupSelectList">
    <item name="android:textSize">16.0sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/list_item_selector</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/dialog_select_height</item>
</style>
```

3.ratio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_selected" android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_normal" android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_normal" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

4.In Adapter's getView

```
CheckedTextView title = (CheckedTextView) convertView
            .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    title.setText(mItems[position]);
    title.setSelected(mCheckedItem == position ? true : false);
                title.setCheckMarkDrawable(position == mCheckedItem ?                   R.drawable.dot_selected
            : R.drawable.dot_normal);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write Custom adapter having CheckBox and textview in adapter layout. Then handle in list's setOnItemClick listener for multiple selection and single selection.

for more you can check this link [How to change ListView Selected items color from default to red without using selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802938/how-to-change-listview-selected-items-color-from-default-to-red-without-using-se)